# wp is_user_logged_in not working on home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having an issue with `is_user_logged_in()` and was hoping to get some help....
the main site URL is http://www.thecuriosityworkshop.com
I'm using `is_user_logged_in()` to echo certain content to signed in users, and it all works fine within the inner pages, but doesn't work on the home page.

Even when I log in as an admin and visit the home page `is_user_logged_in()` shows `false`, but when I go to any of the inner pages, `is_user_logged_in()` shows `true`. Any idea what is happening?

For the sake of testing I'm just doing the following:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  echo 'true';
} else {
  echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you disabled every piece of caching that is occurring?

Comment: Where are you using this code? Which file is it placed in?

Comment: I actually just noticed that the admin bar is also missing from the home/front page when I log in as an admin... I've been so focused on getting the is_user_logged_in function to work, I didn't even noticed that until now.... so the issue is not really with the function, WordPress just doesn't recognize me as a logged in user (only on the home/front page), until I refresh the page. I also disabled all plugins and switched to the twenty fourteen theme, and still same issue. and ideas ?

Comment: do you find any way to solve it? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
//variable for check user logged in
$isUserLogged = false;

//Checks if the current visitor is a logged in user.
if ( !function_exists('is_user_logged_in') ) {

$user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( !empty($user->ID) ) {
       $isUserLogged = true;
    }

} else {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $isUserLogged = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and when I changed my .htaccess file to disable all caching it solved the problem. This is the best code I have found for this:

```
    #prevent caching
    <filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
     FileETag None
     <ifModule mod_headers.c>
      Header unset ETag
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
      Header set Pragma "no-cache"
      Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
  </filesMatch>
```

whether the above code works in your .htacess file or not, try and go to browser tools -> clear browsing data and delete all cache before logging in, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I browsed around a long time, stuck on this.

I had made an extra page, where I used WordPress-authentication.

This was basically it:

**https://example.org/vips-only/login.php**

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php' );
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'This page cannot be accessed directly.' );

if( is_user_logged_in() ){
  echo 'You are logged in, mate';
} else {
  $redirect_to = get_site_url() . '/vips-only/welcome.php';
  wp_login_form([
    'redirect' => $redirect_to
  ]);
}
```

For some reason I couldn't get that `is_user_logged_in()` to work. Even if I first logged in via the 'real' WordPress-login form (and not this custom one I had setup).

**What solved it for me** was to create a new file and copy everything over in that, like: **https://example.org/vips-only/new-login.php**. I have no idea why that worked, but it did.

It might be cookie-related. It might be related to a plugin (I was using [WPS Hide Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/) ). I thought the problem would return, but it hasn't yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and found that the login check function needs to fire within the **'template_redirect'** hook, e.g:

```
function add_login_redirect()
{

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_redirect(home_url('/wp-admin'));
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'add_login_redirect');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put this in **header.php** :

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $logged = TRUE
} else {
    echo 'false';
    $logged = FALSE
}
```

Then just add this condition on any content :

```
if($logged) {
    echo 'Logged in';
} else {
    echo 'not logged in'; 
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code on latest version of wordpress locally and it is also working fine, you can try my trick.

Comment: I guess you could simply do `$logged = is_user_logged_in();`

Comment: Hi @MajidKhan, I already tried something similar to your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. The problem I'm having is when I log in then visit the home page, the is_user_logged_in function shows me as logged out, but as soon as I refresh the page, it shows me as logged in. I'm assuming it's a caching issue, but I don't have any cache plugins installed. I'm using the code in the page-home.php template:

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'true';
    } else {
    echo 'false';
    }

this only happens on the home page. if I visit any of the inner pages, I don't have this issue.